# Как проверить был ли выполнен запрос (prepared statements)?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, preparedstatement

```
 <html>
  <body>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Введите данные о человеке</legend>
        <form method="POST">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="input-area">
                    <label for="name">Имя:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
                </div>

                <div class="input-area">
                    <label for="age">Возраст:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="age" id="age">
                </div>

                <div class="input-area">
                    <label>Пол:</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Мужской
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Женский
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="check" value="1">
            <input type="submit" value="Занести данные в базу">
        </form>
    </fieldset>
    <?php
        require_once "../reg file/login.php";
        $con = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
        if ($con->connect_error) die("Сбой подключения к БД.");

        if (isset($_POST["check"])) {
            if (isset($_POST["name"], $_POST["age"], $_POST["gender"]) === false) {
                die("Вы не ввели одно или несколько полей");
            }

            $name = $_POST["name"];
            $age = $_POST["age"];
            $gender = $_POST["gender"];
            echo $name;
            echo $age;
            echo $gender;
            echo "<br>";
            $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO people(name, age, gender) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("sis", $name, $age, $gemder); //В имени переменной $gender 
//специально допущена ошибка - $gemder, следовательно, запрос 
//не отрабатывает, но "Ошибка" не выводится
            $stmt->execute();
            if ($stmt->affected_rows == 0) die("Ошибка");
            $stmt->close();
        }

        $con->close();

    ?>
</body>
```

В функции bind_param() я специально допустил ошибку в названии переменной $gender, запрос не отработал, но условие проверки правильности запроса почему-то не срабатывает. Как правильно проверять результат работы prepared statements?

Comment: В PHP переменные ж объявляются по факту? ну и создалась новая пустая переменная. которая была присоединена к запросу... ну и был передан и выполнен запрос с пустым значением... но он же был нормально передан, и он был выполнен, пусть и положил в таблицу кривые данные ТАМ, на MySQL... но ТУТ-то никакой ошибки не было.

Comment: проверьте наличие строки в БД, у вас там NULL значение просто в столбце.

Comment: вообще если таки вставка не произошла, т.к. столбец not null, то PDO возвращает либо значение false либо вызывает исключение (если настроено). Проверять для этого число затронутых строк несколько странно. Проверьте, что вернул `execute`

Answer (score 1):

Обратитесь к документации:[`PDOStatement::execute`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php)

> **Возвращаемые значения**
>
> Возвращает `TRUE` в случае успешного завершения или `FALSE` в случае возникновения ошибки.

не надо для этого проверять число затронутых строк, это вообще чисто справочная информация, и совершенно ничего не говорит о корректности запроса.